# get/set C# Key Value pairs from JSON string (without JSON.NET)

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I had a working example parsing a JSON string in a KeyValue class.

For some reason now it is returning 0's and/or nulls.

```
public class KeyValue
{
        //example JSON string: {"SomeCoolPlayerName":{"id":32179899,"name":"SomeCoolPlayerName","profileIconId":547,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1396953413000}}
        public long id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public int profileIconId {get; set;}
        public long summonerLevel {get; set;}
        public long revisionDate {get; set;}

       // public List<int> champions {get; set;}
}
```

Could the JSON string have changed? It is getting populated when I debug I can see it so I added it as a comment above ^^

The web page code is pretty simple also:

```
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var strJSON = client.DownloadString("http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + SummonerName + "?api_key=blanked_on_purpose");
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var KeyValue = ser.Deserialize<KeyValue>(strJSON);
        var summonerId = KeyValue.id;
        //var summonerLevel = KeyValue.summonerLevel;
        txtSummonerId.Text = summonerId.ToString();
    }
```

What must I do to get the summonerId correctly again?

Comment: What does strJSON have when you debug?

Comment: Are you sure your example JSON string is accurate?  According to [the documentation](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/620/1930), the key in the map returned from that API is all lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data has changed.  From the [Change Announcement](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/AFQyEEhZ):

> ### New API Version for Summoners
>
> ...
>
> The response will be map of each summoner ID (or name) to the JSON object containing the requested summoner data.
>
> ...

You had to have changed the version number in your call to `DownloadString()`.  It has been returning a `Map` since v1.3, and you are calling v1.4.  When API version numbers change, you should *expect* the response to change, and check the documentation to see if it has.

Now that your item is contained in a `Map`, you'll need to deserialize it to a `Dictionary<string, KeyValue>`.  According to [the documentation](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/620/1930), the key "is the summoner name in all lower case and with spaces removed".

```
string key = SummonerName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
var KeyValue = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, KeyValue>>(strJSON)[key];
```

(Personally, I'd rename your `KeyValue` class to `Summoner` or `SummonerDto` to match the API.)

Answer (score 2):

In the JSON you gave, the `id` is not in the root object, but is nested under the name `SomeCoolPlayerName`. This can be represented by a dictionary pretty easily:

```
var strJSON = @"{""SomeCoolPlayerName"":{""id"":32179899,""name"":""SomeCoolPlayerName"",""profileIconId"":547,""summonerLevel"":30,""revisionDate"":1396953413000}}";
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, KeyValue>>(strJSON);
// use this if you know the name
var summonerId = dict["SomeCoolPlayerName"].id; // 32179899
// or this if you know there's only one value in the dictionary
var summonerId = dict.Single().Value.id; // 32179899
```